# converting all link action properties Named destination to Page number to set ZoomLevel Inherit Zoom

Tags: itext

I have one pdf file which includes multiple internal links and all links action properties values is  **Named Destination**

I need to set ZoomLevel=Inherit Zoom values for all link

I Try to convert link action properties from Named Destination to Page number to set ZoomLevel=InheritZoom for all links.

link action properties is changed successfully but ZoomLevel set as **Custom**, but I need set **InheritZoom**

I have used below sample code of iText5 to achieve result

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
 reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();


 public void LinkZoomLevel(PdfReader reader) {
  try {
    int totalPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int count = 0; count < totalPages; count++) {
        PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(count + 1);

        PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if (annots != null) {
            int annotationSize = annots.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < annotationSize; i++) {
                PdfDictionary annotation = annots.getAsDict(i);
                if (PdfName.LINK.equals(annotation
                        .getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {
                    if (annotation.get(PdfName.A) == null)
                        continue;
                    PdfDictionary action = annotation
                            .getAsDict(PdfName.A);
                    PdfArray destArray;
                    if (action != null) {
                        destArray = action.getAsArray(PdfName.D);

                        // destArray getting null for all links 

                        if (destArray != null) {
                            if (PdfName.FITR.equals(destArray
                                        .getAsName(1))) {
                                    destArray.set(1, PdfName.XYZ);
                                    destArray.set(2, destArray
                                            .getAsNumber(2));
                                    destArray.set(3, destArray
                                            .getAsNumber(5));
                                    destArray.set(4, new PdfNumber(0));
                                    destArray.remove(5);
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

PdfDictionary annotation = annots.getAsDict(i);
 annotation value is like-> {/Border=[0, 0, 0], /Type=/Annot, /F=4, /Dest=[170 0 R, /FitR, 0, 649, 573, 649], /Rect=[278.305, 161.745, 283.294, 171.723], /Subtype=/Link}
```

Thanks in advance